# How to clear the entire array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array like this:

```
Dim aFirstArray() As Variant
```

How do I clear the entire array?
What about a collection?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can either use the `Erase` or `ReDim` statements to clear the array. Examples of each are shown in [the MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/erase-statement). For example:

```
Dim threeDimArray(9, 9, 9), twoDimArray(9, 9) As Integer
Erase threeDimArray, twoDimArray
ReDim threeDimArray(4, 4, 9)
```

To remove a collection, you iterate over its items and use the `Remove` method:

```
For i = 1 to MyCollection.Count
  MyCollection.Remove 1 ' Remove first item
Next i
```

Comment: Just a quick note, at least for VBA, you can't ReDim an array that was declared with dimensions.

Comment: +1 @KevenDenen that's true, but the array in the original question wasn't declared with dimensions. @Sarfraz great answer but your link is for VB.Net. I can't find a link for VBA. Here's the link for the VB6 manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243360(v=VS.60).aspx

Comment: Sarfraz, is there a reason you wouldn't just say: MyCollection = new Collection. Why iterate over it?

Comment: what if I simply call `ReDim`? Does it simply reset to zero the values or does it allocate a while new array? My concerns are about time-performances when calling `ReDim` to reset a big array in a loop

Comment: note : the last line (redim) is not needed if the array is module-wide declared.

Comment: This all don't work with the test "IsEmpty(aFirstArray)". I added an answer for that purpose

Answer (score 29):

For deleting a dynamic array in VBA use the instruction `Erase`.

Example:

```
Dim ArrayDin() As Integer    
ReDim ArrayDin(10)    'Dynamic allocation 
Erase ArrayDin        'Erasing the Array
```

Hope this help!

Comment: What was the reason to post an answer two years after the question was asked, provided this very answer has already been posted?

Comment: @GSerg that is a very well-phrased sentence.

Comment: Worthless comments to the both of you.  No answer demonstrates Erase.  Furthermore, it's almost a year after Andres posted his answer and it actually gave me the one-line code solution I was looking for.  If I could downvote both of your comments, I would.

Comment: Added comments are useful for those of us who look at them at a later date - such as my using this answer in Dec of 2018.  Thank you Andres for taking the time to post.

Answer (score 7):

It is as simple as :

```
Erase aFirstArray
```

Comment: Same answer as the one Andres posted 4 years earlier. Can't see how that is useful.

Answer (score 4):

Find a better use for myself:
I usually test if a variant is empty, and all of the above methods fail with the test. I found that you can actually set a variant to empty:

```
Dim aTable As Variant
If IsEmpty(aTable) Then
    'This is true
End If
ReDim aTable(2)
If IsEmpty(aTable) Then
    'This is False
End If
ReDim aTable(2)
aTable = Empty
If IsEmpty(aTable) Then
    'This is true
End If
ReDim aTable(2)
Erase aTable
If IsEmpty(aTable) Then
    'This is False
End If
```

this way i get the behaviour i want

Answer (score 3):

```
[your Array name] = Empty
```

Then the array will be without content and can be filled again.

Comment: This doesn't work. You get a "Compile error: Can't assign to array"

Comment: for an array of variant your solution is better than the erase, because using your solution I can check later on if array is empty by doing if isempty(MyArray), while if we use erase it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
ReDim aFirstArray(0)
```

This will resize the array to zero and erase all data.

Comment: no, this will keep 1 element in the array with index 0

Answer (score 0):

i fell into a case where clearing the entire array failed with dim/redim :

having 2 module-wide arrays, Private inside a userform,

One array is dynamic and uses a class module, the other is fixed and has a special type.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type Perso_Type
   Nom As String
   PV As Single 'Long 'max 1
   Mana As Single 'Long
   Classe1 As String
   XP1 As Single
   Classe2 As String
   XP2 As Single
   Classe3 As String
   XP3 As Single
   Classe4 As String
   XP4 As Single
   Buff(1 To 10) As IPicture 'Disp
   BuffType(1 To 10) As String
   Dances(1 To 10) As IPicture 'Disp
   DancesType(1 To 10) As String
End Type

Private Data_Perso(1 To 9, 1 To 8) As Perso_Type

Dim ImgArray() As New ClsImage 'ClsImage is a Class module
```

And i have a sub declared as public to clear those arrays (and associated run-time created controls) from inside and outside the userform like this :

```
Public Sub EraseControlsCreatedAtRunTime()
Dim i As Long
On Error Resume Next
With Me.Controls 'removing all on run-time created controls of the Userform :
    For i = .Count - 1 To 0 Step -1 
        .Remove i
    Next i
End With
Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0

Erase ImgArray, Data_Perso
'ReDim ImgArray() As ClsImage ' i tried this, no error but wouldn't work correctly
'ReDim Data_Perso(1 To 9, 1 To 8) As Perso_Type 'without the erase not working, with erase this line is not needed.
End Sub
```

note : this last sub was first called from outside (other form and class module) with `Call FormName.SubName` but had to replace it with `Application.Run FormName.SubName` , less errors, don't ask why...

Answer (score 0):

Only use `Redim` statement

```
 Dim aFirstArray() As Variant

Redim aFirstArray(nRows,nColumns)
```